# How to use JObject.SelectToken to parse json properties that start with @?

Tags: c#, json.net

Given the following json:

```
{
     "Test": {
          "@id": "abcdef"
     }
}
```

How can I use JObject.SelectToken() to retrieve the value of @id?

I've tried:

```
JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(json);

jobject.SelectToken("Test.@id").Value<string>()
jobject.SelectToken(@"Test.\@id").Value<string>()    
jobject.SelectToken("[Test].[@id]").Value<string>()
jobject.SelectToken(@"[Test].[\@id]").Value<string>()
```

Comment: jobject.SelectToken("Test.@id").Value<string>() works properly

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work using:

```
jobject.SelectToken("Test['@id']").Value<string>()
```

The important part is the single quotes from what I can tell.